# utf8 values insert into mysql database from form text box

Tags: jsp

jdbc does not gives fact values when want to insert utf-8 into mysql databse. gives ??????

```
<%
    String conUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school1?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8";
    String userName="root";
    String pass="system";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl,userName,pass);

    String firstname = new String(request.getParameter("fName").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8"); 
    String email = new String(request.getParameter("eMail").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");    System.out.print(firstname); 
    System.out.print(email); 
try { 
  st.executeUpdate("insert into std values('"+firstname+"','"+email+"')"); 
}
catch(Exception e1) { 
  System.out.print(e1); 
} %>
```

Comment: String firstname = new String(request.getParameter("fName").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
            String email = new String(request.getParameter("eMail").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
           System.out.print(firstname);
           System.out.print(email);
         try
         {
               st.executeUpdate("insert into std values('"+firstname+"','"+email+"')");
               
         }catch(Exception e1)
         {
             System.out.print(e1);
         }  
        %>

Comment: Why are you getting the bytes as ISO-8859-1 and trying to convert to utf8? Browsers send utf8 already so that's not needed. You probably need to convert your table's encoding to utf8.

Comment: dear friend, i have already created table and databse in utf8 format,